# How To Use Kunststube-CSRFP?

Tags: php

I put [Kunststube-CSRFP](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP) demo.php on my server : `http://domain1.com/demo.php` and hit 'TRY IT' button and it says : **Form submission ok.**

then I look at the source code and copy the token generated by the script into another server (domain2.com) and try to make fake HTML form there :

```
<form action="http://domain1.com/demo.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="1356266422:QaAnM2IolCk9K1Mme3rOGifwmfmdldzdyg/PBu4ht818lIu52ArKFG2HxUOztmcgwblLcIgymaNheuGY7g6Kg==:nvhnqxfM9upP/UT+FRGf0nXDILFPHaubfdjahVYSm2w9fFHKQ/bQQ6rapjdKN8ype9qaX8TkAZJpxg9RmH8ZM9YWA==" name="_token">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and when I hit 'Submit' button from domain2.php... surprisingly, demo.php on first server (domain1.com) process the token just like from itself and display same string : **Form submission ok.**

shouldn't be "**Token INVALID.**" come out if it's not submitted from same server? where did I go wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't be "Token INVALID." come out if it's not submitted from same server?

No.

The point of the token is to prevent Mallory (who controls a malicious server) from making Alice's web browser submit bad data to Bob's web server.

In this case, Alice controls the server the request is coming from. Alice is trusted and has access to the token.

Alice can make any request she likes.

> then I look at the source code

Mallory can't do that. She has no way to get the token, so she can't trick Alice isn't making a request that Mallory wants to be made.

Comment: okay bro, it seems that I misunderstand of what Kunststube-CSRFP used for. I thought it can validate if a form submitted from same server or not. any idea what can validate it?

Comment: There is no way to ensure that a form is submitted from a particular server. You can only authenticate/authorize users and test/reject/sanitise/escape the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is the submitting of form data from a third party server to your server, using the fact that an unsuspecting user is logged into your server and forcing him to cause certain actions on your server without the user's intention.

CSRF tokens prevent this by requiring a valid token to be submitted with each form. A third party cannot get these tokens without active participation of the user. So a third party can "fake" form submissions from their site to yours, but they won't have the valid CSRF token, which helps you distinguish such fake requests from real ones. A third party cannot get such tokens since the Javascript cross-site scripting rules in the browser prevent the browser from fetching data from third party sites (though they do not prevent the *submission* of data to third party sites).

That's also why you should tie the token to a user id. A third party may be able to get *a* valid token from your server and include it in the "fake" form, but they should not be able to get a *user specific* token.

If you give a third party the token explicitly, you are subverting your own CSRF protection.